# ProductLineItem FreeGift changes where we don't expect it to

Tags: intershop

We are having some strange problems with free gifts.

After calling `ProcessBasket-RemoveLineItem`, flag `FreeGift` in `ProductLineItem` that remain in the basket is changed from true to false.

It looks like the problem is in `InvalidateBasketCalculation` pipelet (from bc_basket), called in `ProcessBasketInvalidation-SetBasketInvalidationStatus`.

[image]

Comment: please add MCVE and use the quote tags available in the editor for your code.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information whether a product is a free gift is stored in the `ComputedItems` of the basket calculation results. By calling the pipeline `ProcessBasket-RemoveLineItem`, the basket calculation results are marked as invalid (as you correctly found out this is done by the pipelet `InvalidateBasketCalculation`). As a result, existing `ComputedItems` will be removed, as they may no longer be correct (note that this is a recent change that has been introduced with ICM 7.10.5.5; if you're using an older version there may be other causes for this problem). So the information whether a product is a free gift gets lost at this point of time.

To fix this, simply trigger the basket calculation again by calling pipeline `ProcessBasket-Calculate`.